# Combining lists, possibly with mapply

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a list of lists  - a simple example is given below:

```
my_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = 4)
my_list[[1]] <- c(1, 2, 3)
my_list[[2]] <- c(1, 2, 6)
my_list[[3]] <- c("A")
my_list[[4]] <- c("A", "B")
```

I would like to combine a subset of these lists based on their indices in a vector. For example if
`my_indices <- c(1,2,3)`, I would like to combine the first three lists and eliminates duplicates to get

```
c(1, 2, 3, 6, "A")
```

I can do this manually as follows:

```
c(my_list[[1]], my_list[[2]], my_list[[3]]) %>% 
      unique()
[1] "1" "2" "3" "6" "A"
```

but when i try and simplify / generalize this to

```
my_indices <- c(1, 2, 3)
c(my_list[[my_indices ]]) %>% 
  unique()
```

I get an error message:

```
error in my_list[[my_indices]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

How can i combine lists in this setting. I do want a general solution, as my list of lists is large, and I want to be able to extract any subset of it. I have seen posts that use `mapply` in a related setting, but have not successfully got it to work.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution using `reduce`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = 4)
my_list[[1]] <- c(1, 2, 3)
my_list[[2]] <- c(1, 2, 6)
my_list[[3]] <- c("A")
my_list[[4]] <- c("A", "B")

to_merge <- c(1,2,3)
unique(reduce(my_list[to_merge], c))
#> [1] "1" "2" "3" "6" "A"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you both - this is more subtle than I would have thought.

Answer (score 2):

`c(1, 2, 3, 6, "A")` is not what you think, it will be converted to `c("1", "2", "3", "6", "A")`. If you want mixed class, you cannot `unlist`, it must stay a list.

Some thoughts:

```r
my_list[my_indices]
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 6
# [[3]]
# [1] "A"

unlist(my_list[my_indices])
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "1" "2" "6" "A"
unique(unlist(my_list[my_indices]))
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "6" "A"
```

To preserve class and ensure uniqueness, you can do

```r
func <- function(a, b) {
  a_chrs <- as.character(a)
  b_chrs <- as.character(b)
  b[ match(setdiff(b_chrs, a_chrs), b_chrs) ]
}
Reduce(func, my_list[my_indices], accumulate = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# [[2]]
# [1] 6
# [[3]]
# [1] "A"
```

The `_chrs` fancy footwork is because `setdiff` by itself will not reduce correctly:

```r
out <- Reduce(setdiff, my_list[my_indices], accumulate = TRUE)
out
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# [[2]]
# [1] 3
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
```

If you need that with individually-indexable values, then

```r
unlist(lapply(out, as.list), recursive = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
# [[4]]
# [1] 6
# [[5]]
# [1] "A"
```